# Join three files in single mapreduce program

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce

how to join three large dataset in a single mapreduce program.All these three files can not fit in memory.The file1 has key K1,file2 has K2 and file3 has both k1 and k2.I want to join File1 and File2 by referencing File3.Please let me know if there is any technique to do this. Thanks in advanced...!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a single mapreduce job. Since you have to create two separate custom writable class one for input 1 and input 2(key has to be field k1 or k2 and a join identifier) and a separate one for input 3(key has to be field k1,k2 and a join identifier). So it requires two mapreduce jobs.

MR 1(Join input 1 and input 3 based on key K1).

Mapper 1

Map output:

**(K,V)=>((K1,input1),value)**

Mapper 2

Map Output:

**(K,V)=>((K1,input3),value)**

Append/Join data set in reducers.

MR2(Join input 2 and output of MR 1 based on key K2)

Mapper 1:

Map Output:

**(K,V)=>((K2,input2),value)**

Mapper 2:

Map Output:

**(K,V)=>((K2,outputofMR1),value)**

Append/Join data sets in reducer